# Hover on multiple Div at same time to make it look like 1 div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 4 divs each have same class and they are next to each other in a grid of multiple other divs, but the divs I want to add an hover affect can also vary, now it is 4 but on a different area it can be 6 or more or less.

Basically I want to hover over the div with the same class and make them look like 1 large div.

```css
.divTable{
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
}
.divTableRow {
 display: table-row;
}
.divTableHeading {
 background-color: #EEE;
 display: table-header-group;
}
.divTableCell, .divTableHead {
 border: 1px solid #999999;
 display: table-cell;
 padding: 3px 10px;
  width:40px;
  height:30px;
}
.divTableCellActive{
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.divTableCell:hover{
background-color:green;
}

.divTableHeading {
 background-color: #EEE;
 display: table-header-group;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.divTableFoot {
 background-color: #EEE;
 display: table-footer-group;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.divTableBody {
 display: table-row-group;
}

.box {
  /*position: relative;*/
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  display: table-cell;
 padding: 3px 10px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 1px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 1px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
}

.box::after {
  content: "";
  border-radius: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
}

.box:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.25, 1.25);
  transform: scale(1.25, 1.25);
}

.box:hover::after {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="divTable">
<div class="divTableBody">
<div class="divTableRow">
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div class="divTableRow">
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell divTableCellActive"></div>
<div class="divTableCell divTableCellActive"></div>
<div class="divTableCell divTableCellActive"></div>
<div class="divTableCell divTableCellActive"></div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div class="divTableRow">
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div class="divTableRow">
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="divTable" style="margin-top:2em;">
<div class="divTableBody">
<div class="divTableRow">
<div class="divTableCell"></div>
<div class="divTableCell"></div>
<div class="divTableCell"></div>
<div class="divTableCell"></div>
<div class="divTableCell"></div>
<div class="divTableCell"></div>
<div class="divTableCell"></div>
<div class="divTableCell"></div>
<div class="divTableCell"></div>
<div class="divTableCell"></div>
</div>
<div class="divTableRow">
<div class="divTableCell"></div>
<div class="divTableCell"></div>
<div class="divTableCell"></div>
<div class="box divTableCellActive"></div>
<div class="box divTableCellActive"></div>
<div class="box divTableCellActive"></div>
<div class="box divTableCellActive"></div>
<div class="divTableCell"></div>
<div class="divTableCell"></div>
<div class="divTableCell"></div>
</div>
<div class="divTableRow">
<div class="divTableCell"></div>
<div class="divTableCell"></div>
<div class="divTableCell"></div>
<div class="divTableCell"></div>
<div class="divTableCell"></div>
<div class="divTableCell"></div>
<div class="divTableCell"></div>
<div class="divTableCell"></div>
<div class="divTableCell"></div>
<div class="divTableCell"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using jQuery `toggleClass` function to add an effect class, then customize it to your desire.

```js
$(".divTableCellActive").hover(function(){
    $(".divTableCellActive").toggleClass("effect");
});
```

```css
.divTable{
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
}
.divTableRow {
 display: table-row;
}
.divTableHeading {
 background-color: #EEE;
 display: table-header-group;
}
.divTableCell, .divTableHead {
 border: 1px solid #999999;
 display: table-cell;
 padding: 3px 10px;
  width:40px;
  height:30px;
}
.divTableCellActive{
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.divTableCellActive.effect{
  background-color: green;
}

.divTableCell:hover{
background-color:green;
}

.divTableHeading {
 background-color: #EEE;
 display: table-header-group;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.divTableFoot {
 background-color: #EEE;
 display: table-footer-group;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.divTableBody {
 display: table-row-group;
}

.box {
  /*position: relative;*/
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  display: table-cell;
 padding: 3px 10px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 1px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 1px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
}

.box::after {
  content: "";
  border-radius: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
}

.box:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.25, 1.25);
  transform: scale(1.25, 1.25);
}

.box:hover::after {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divTable">
<div class="divTableBody">
<div class="divTableRow">
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div class="divTableRow">
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell divTableCellActive"></div>
<div class="divTableCell divTableCellActive"></div>
<div class="divTableCell divTableCellActive"></div>
<div class="divTableCell divTableCellActive"></div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div class="divTableRow">
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div class="divTableRow">
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="divTable" style="margin-top:2em;">
<div class="divTableBody">
<div class="divTableRow">
<div class="divTableCell"></div>
<div class="divTableCell"></div>
<div class="divTableCell"></div>
<div class="divTableCell"></div>
<div class="divTableCell"></div>
<div class="divTableCell"></div>
<div class="divTableCell"></div>
<div class="divTableCell"></div>
<div class="divTableCell"></div>
<div class="divTableCell"></div>
</div>
<div class="divTableRow">
<div class="divTableCell"></div>
<div class="divTableCell"></div>
<div class="divTableCell"></div>
<div class="box divTableCellActive"></div>
<div class="box divTableCellActive"></div>
<div class="box divTableCellActive"></div>
<div class="box divTableCellActive"></div>
<div class="divTableCell"></div>
<div class="divTableCell"></div>
<div class="divTableCell"></div>
</div>
<div class="divTableRow">
<div class="divTableCell"></div>
<div class="divTableCell"></div>
<div class="divTableCell"></div>
<div class="divTableCell"></div>
<div class="divTableCell"></div>
<div class="divTableCell"></div>
<div class="divTableCell"></div>
<div class="divTableCell"></div>
<div class="divTableCell"></div>
<div class="divTableCell"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```